# It does not show me placeholder and name attributes

Tags: javascript

```
function createNoteElement(id, content) {
  const element = document.createElement("tectarea");
  element.id="w3review";
  element.name="w3review";
  element.placeholder="Describe yourself here...";
  element.maxlength="50";
  element.classList.add("note");
  element.value=content;    
  element.addEventListener("change", () => {
    updateNote(id, element.value); 
  });
}
```

Comment: It seems as though the code has not been entirely put in the code block. You might want to fix that as it is confusing. It is also not clear what the "updateNote" function is. Apparently. the closing of the function is also missing.

Also, you have a type in "textarea". Perhaps, that is already the issue. But I don't think we have enough information to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have a typo: `tectarea` should be `textarea`.
2. You don't [append your element to the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Here's a working example.

```js
function updateNote(id, value) {
  console.log(id, value);
}

function createNoteElement(id, content) {
  const element = document.createElement('textarea');
  element.id  =id;
  element.name = id;
  element.placeholder = 'Describe yourself here...';
  element.maxlength = '50';
  element.classList.add('note');
  element.value = content;    
  element.addEventListener('change', () => {
    updateNote(id, element.value);
  });
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}

createNoteElement('w3review', 'This is some content');
```